# What causes my borderless C++/CLI app to crash when overriding WndProc?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I use a form with border NONE. I need to override WndProc for resize and move form. However, using this code, my app crashes!

```
 static const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
 static const int HTCLIENT = 1;
 static const int HTCAPTION = 2;

 protected: virtual void Form1::WndProc(System::Windows::Forms::Message %m) override 
 {        
     switch (m.Msg)
     {
         case WM_NCHITTEST:
             if (m.Result == IntPtr(HTCLIENT))
             {
                 m.Result = IntPtr(HTCAPTION);
             }
             break;
     }
     Form1::WndProc(m);
 }       


virtual System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ get() override
{

    System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ cp = __super::CreateParams;
    cp->Style |= 0x40000; 
    return cp;
}
```

How can I fix my code not to crash but still allow my form to be moved and resized?

Comment: For future reference, it's always best to include what *exactly* you mean by "crashes" in your questions. Is there an exception thrown? Do you get a compiler error? Does your computer explode? That makes it easier for us to know what types of things to look for in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the base class's `WndProc` method *first*, in order for `m.Result` to be set to the correct value. The code you posted doesn't call it until the *end*.

Additionally, you're trying to call the base class with `Form1::WndProc`, which actually calls the *current* class's implementation of the `WndProc` method. That's why your application is "crashing" every time you try to run it with a `StackOverflowException`—your code within the `WndProc` method is calling itself recursively. Directly calling the superclass's implementation (like you did in the `CreateParams` property) with the `__super` keyword works just fine.

So, you need to re-write that method like this:

```
virtual void Form1::WndProc(System::Windows::Forms::Message %m) override 
{
    __super::WndProc(m);

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        if (m.Result == IntPtr(HTCLIENT))
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr(HTCAPTION);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the warnings you get on this code:

> warning C4717:
>   'cpptemp5::Form1::WndProc' : recursive
>   on all control paths, function will
>   cause runtime stack overflow

Which is why your code crashes with this web site name.  That could have been a bit more than a warning.  Fix:

```
 Form::WndProc(m);
```

Or use the __super keyword.  It should be called first, before you change the return value.

---

> warning C4490: 'override' : incorrect
>   use of override specifier;
>   'cpptemp5::Form1::get' does not match
>   a base ref class method

Which prevents your attempt at overriding from working, the form still has borders.  The better mousetrap is to assign the FormBorderStyle property in the constructor:

```
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
    }
```

Although you'd normally just do this with the designer, using the Properties window.  For completeness, the override doesn't work because you made it a function, not a property.  The correct syntax is:

```
protected:
    property System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ CreateParams {
        virtual System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ get() override {
            System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ cp = __super::CreateParams;
            cp->Style |= 0x40000;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

But not quite good enough to make the form borderless.